# Multiple Institutes per Line in Title Slide

Tags: beamer, line-breaking, titles

I'm making a talk in `beamer` where I have to acknowledge about 10 authors, all from different institutions. By default `beamer` puts multiple authors per line, but only one institute per line. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\title{Title}
\author{Me\inst{1} \and Someone\inst{2}}
\institute[short]{\inst{1} First \and \inst{2} Second}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Obviously this case is fine: there are only two institutes listed. But when I add many more I'm running out of space on the slide, is there some way to put multiple institutes on each line?

Answer (score 5):

By default, `\and` is set to insert a line-break (and vertically skip `1em`... technically `\\[1em]`) within `\institute`. To that end, define your own `\samelineand` that doesn't insert this vertical skip:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\title{Title}
\author{Me\inst{1} \and Someone\inst{2} \and Someone else\inst{3}}
\institute[short]{\inst{1} First \samelineand \inst{2} Second \samelineand \inst{3} Third}
\newcommand{\samelineand}{\qquad}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Above I defined `\samelineand` to be equivalent to `\qquad`, but you can change it to whatever you need. A new line-break can be inserted using `\and` again.